# Prioritize Strong Ciphers in Jetty6 [JAVA]

Tags: java, ssl, jetty

Unfortunately I have to stick with Jetty6 for stupid reasons and I have to prioritize AES128-SHA and AES256-SHA over other ciphers.  Jetty6 doesn't have setIncludeCipherSuites option in its channel connector.  How can I achieve this?

I saw suggestions about using System properties such as https.cipherSuites but they didn't help me.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: `https.cipherSuites` is for `HttpsURLConnection`. Nothing to do with Jetty.

Comment: Thanks for your responses Joakim and EJP.  Joakim, I agree with every word you said, but like I mentioned earlier, I can't upgrade the Jetty version due to reasons.  I realized how much of customization work it will take, so went for customizing SslSelectChannelConnector instead to override createSSLEngine method and enable only desired ciphers.  This in no way solves the original problem, but I adjusted my requirements due to constraints.

Answer (score 2):

Jetty 6 was EOL (End of Life) back in 2010.

> It is not safe to use Jetty 6 with modern SSL/TLS requirements, as Jetty 6 does not support 80% of the now required features and configurations that have evolved over the past years with regards to modern SSL/TLS.
>
> Also note that Java itself has strong language around SSL/TLS and the requirement to keep your Java installation up to date as well (don't forget, Java VMs have an expiration date.  If you use SSL/TLS, then the expiration of the JVM is an important consideration in your plans.  Ignore it at your own peril)

The concept/ability to control cipher order (in Jetty) was introduced in Jetty 9.x and finalized with the TLS/1.2 work in Jetty 9.3.0

In order to support your require will require heavy customization of the Jetty 6 codebase. (the svn repository is no longer online! as codehaus.org has been shut down)